# How to place turtles in a portion of a raster dataset?

Tags: netlogo

From `GIS extension`, I imported into Netlogo a raster that I represented in orange in figure below. My objective is to randomly place one turtle in each block of the raster represented in blue (namely in the 9 blocks). The blue raster is a portion of the orange raster.

Here is my code to randomly place turtles in blocks

```
let number 1
ask n-of number patches with [ (max-pxcor - ((x-increment + 1) * (max-pxcor / 3))) <= pxcor and pxcor <= (max-pxcor - (x-increment * (max-pxcor / 3))) and (max-pycor - ((y-increment + 1) * (max-pycor / 3))) <= pycor and pycor <= (max-pycor - (y-increment * (max-pycor / 3))) ] [
sprout 1 ]
```

From my orange raster in Netlogo, how can I apply the code above in only the blue raster ?

Here my rasters:

[image]

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ask patches with [pcolor = blue] [
  sprout 1
]
```

I suspect that doesn't answer your question. But that's because I don't understand your question. If you can tell me why the above code isn't what you're looking for, then perhaps I can improve it to be more helpful.

Note that it doesn't really make sense to talk about the "orange raster" and "blue raster". The GIS extension knows how to import rasters into the NetLogo world, but once they've been imported, they aren't rasters anymore. All that's left after the import finishes is turtles and patches. If you can use the vocabulary of turtles and patches to ask your question, rather than the vocabulary of "rasters", you'll have a better chance of formulating a clear, answerable question.